# make request to nodejs from html javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, request

I have 3 files: app.js, index.html and script.js;

script.js is script that make request to bing text to speech API. When i run in console, it works properly: I run script with text as an argument, and it returns me a speech of my text. while app.js is creating server and runs index.html.

In index.html i need to type text and pass it to script.js as parameter, and take voice as response. Any ideas how can I execute script.js from html page?

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIrx9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply include the contents of `script.js` in the `index.html` file within a `<script>` tag, or add a link to the file like so:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <!–– keep your current index.html contents, and simply add the line below: ––>
        <script src= "script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This assumes that all of your files are in the same directory